# random sleep between a set of time

Tags: c#

<strike>I want to create a program that when ever the user click on the start button, the program will sleep between 3 sec to 10 sec and then a button will appear to allow the user to click on that button, then the time will print out and tell the user how long it take in milliseconds for the user to click on the button.</strike>

I know that I need to use `Thread.Sleep()` and `Environment.TickCount()`

The problem is I don't know how to make the program sleep random between 3-10 sec

Thank you for the answer. Everything is working however a tiny problem occur

The problem is the first label doesn't write out "Get ready..." but it sleep for 3-10 sec before it print out "Get ready...". What i want is that the program print out "Get ready..." and then go to sleep for 3-10 sec.

Here is the code:

```
    //Starts the count
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Get ready...";

        //Generate random sleeptime
        Random waitTime = new Random();
        seconds = waitTime.Next(3 * 1000, 11 * 1000);

        //Put the thread to sleep
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(seconds);

        //Show the button
        btnNow.Show();
        label2.Text = "NOW!";

        //Count the time in milliseconds
        start = Environment.TickCount;
    }
```

Comment: There is a class `System.Random`, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.random.aspx).

Comment: Sleep takes milliseconds and with the Random class you can produce randomnumbers. Now you have all the bits you need to start coding.

Comment: @rene intentional pun?

Comment: @ChrisCooney yes...do I need to add that more explicitely?

Comment: @rene Nope. I chuckled. Good work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the Random class:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int number = rnd.Next(3,11);
```

Have a look at the reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

Note that the first integer parameter is inclusive, while the second paramter is exclusive. So you have to use 11 and not 10. (If you want to exclude 10 seconds you have to change that of course to "10").

You can multiply this number with 1000 to get your milliseconds value and use Thread.Sleep with that value.

Comment: Don't create a new Random object every time though as doing so, depending on how often the code is executed, may give you the same "random" number each time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Everything is working however a tiny problem occur

The problem is the first label doesn't write out "Get ready..." but it sleep for 3-10 sec before it print out "Get ready...". What i want is that the program print out "Get ready..." and then go to sleep for 3-10 sec.

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
Random random = new Random();
mseconds=random.Next(3, 10) * 1000;   
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(mseconds);
```

Comment: Don't create a new Random object every time though as doing so, depending on how often the code is executed, may give you the same "random" number each time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Everything is working however a tiny problem occur

The problem is the first label doesn't write out "Get ready..." but it sleep for 3-10 sec before it print out "Get ready...". What i want is that the program print out "Get ready..." and then go to sleep for 3-10 sec.

Comment: @VoDanh try Application.DoEvents() after setting the text to the label.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the text is not changing is because you are putting the gui thread in sleep mode.
You can fix this by calling the Application.DoEvents method after you changed the label text but it would be better to do the counting in a separate thread.